# UI on installed app is not showing some tables and yet they show on android emulator (Pixel 4 API 28) before building the apk

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The apk build completes normally without any errors but shows this message;

"Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 1928 bytes (99.9% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app."

I highly doubt it might be the cause because the table on one page shows and doesn't show on another.

This is the Landing page[landing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcC4w.jpg)

This table shows on both emulator and installed app[pending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Tjl.jpg)

This table shows on emulator only[report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha62n.jpg)

This is the code for the page where table is only showing on emulator;

//table begins here
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
child: Table(
//table border styling
border: const TableBorder(
top: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey),
bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey),
left: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey),
right: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey),
horizontalInside: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey),
),
defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,

```
            //column width
            columnWidths: const {
              0: FlexColumnWidth(40),
              1: FlexColumnWidth(35),
              2: FlexColumnWidth(22),
            },
            children: [
              //first table row
              TableRow(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 228, 228, 228),
                ),
                children: [
                  TableCell(
                    verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Entity Name',
                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TableCell(
                    verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Submission Date',
                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                            fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TableCell(
                    verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Status',
                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                            fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              //second table row
              TableRow(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                children: [
                  TableCell(
                    verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '',
                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TableCell(
                    verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '',
                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                            fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: TableCell(
                      verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                            backgroundColor: const Color(0xff166955),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const EntityDetails(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            'APPROVED',
                            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              //third table row
              TableRow(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 250, 250, 250),
                ),
                children: [
                  TableCell(
                    verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

                      //entity name
                      child: Text(
                        '',
                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TableCell(
                    verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '',
                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                            fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: TableCell(
                      verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 30,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                            backgroundColor: const Color(0xff166955),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            'APPROVED',
                            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: It might layout issue, check that if that's case try to build a dynamic layout that support the different screens size.